# Flink dataset api delivery guarantee and checkpointing

Tags: apache-flink

Flink documentation mentions delivery guarantee of exactly once or atleast once for data stream api, however, I found no reference of the same for data set api.

Are messages guaranteed to be delivered exactly once to all transformations in data sets; further, in the absence of checkpoint mechanism, the only logical recourse is to start the job from the beginning?

Can i use data stream api for batch job, what would i lose?

Answer (score 0):

Fault tolerance for the DataSet api is described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/batch/fault_tolerance.html), and yes, it is based on retrying the failed job.

You certainly can use the DataStream api for finite (batch) jobs. There are a few features that are only present in the batch api, such as the machine learning and graph libraries, and the DataSet api has some optimizations that aren't available for DataStreams, but for many applications the differences aren't significant.